# Python BeautifulSoup - preparing HTML rows and td tags for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse a bunch of combined tables' rows, row by row, column by column to prepare it for import into Pandas. I can't use `to_html()` because one of the columns has a list of tag links in each cell.

The data structure is the same in all the tables. But there are a couple of particular columns I'd like to drop: `td.a.img` and `td.div` with `{'class': 'stars'}`. So a couple of questions:

1. Should I be dropping the columns before importing to Pandas or add extra column names in the header before importing to Pandas and then unwanted dropping columns? I've done both and don't know if one's better than the other. The wishy-washiness is messing me up.
2. **[ANSWERED IN UPDATE]** Assuming dropping the columns BEFORE importing to Pandas: I can't figure out the correct method to skip a `td.div` tag containing the class attribute `'stars'`. My following code works but it doesn't seem like the correct method. I can't just do a `if col.div: continue` because some of the required columns have extra `<div>` tags I need for later.
3. As a secondary question, my `collect_book_rows_from_html_files()` takes about 9-10 seconds to run on 34 files. Each table has 100 rows. Total of rows is ~3380. Is there a better way to get the
   table data from each file? I have 2 methods I've used to read in rows. Method 2 seems better to me, but maybe there's a better way?

I'd appreciate any insights.

```py
    def collect_book_rows_from_html_files(self):
        tic = time.perf_counter()
        for file in self.cache_files:
            with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), features="lxml", parse_only=SoupStrainer('table'))
                rows = soup.find_all('tr')[1:]
                ## method 1: 
                ## self.html_rows.extend([row for row in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]])
            self.html_rows.extend(rows) # method 2
            
        toc = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"Total time to extract HTML tables from files: {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")

    def extract_data_from_html_rows(self):
        for row in self.html_rows:
            new_row = self.rebuild_row(row)
            self.final_html_rows.append(new_row.copy())

    def rebuild_row(self, row):
        new_row = []
        for col in row.find_all('td'):
            if col.div:
                if 'stars' in str(col.div.attrs):
                    continue
            if col.a:
                if col.a.img:
                    continue
                else:
                    new_row.append(self.handle_links(col)) # returns a tuple of (name, url)
            else:
                if not col.text or not col.text.strip():
                    new_row.append(['NaN'])
                else:
                    new_text = self.clean_tag_text(col)
                    new_row.append(new_text)
        return new_row
```

**UPDATE:**
This is an answer to Question 2 from my more focused question on stackoverflow.com[python-beautifulsoup-parsing-an-html-table-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74959245/)

```
class ParseTools:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def is_empty_dir(self, dir_name: str) -> bool:
        return not any(os.scandir(str(dir_name)))
        
    def get_cache_files(self, dir):
        '''Get html file names'''
        if self.is_empty_dir(dir):
            return []
        else:
            files = [os.path.join(dir, file) for file in os.listdir(dir)]
            files = [WindowsPath(entry) for entry in files]
            checked_files = [entry for entry in files if entry.is_file() and 'html' in str(entry)]
            return checked_files


class HTMLFileParser(ParseTools):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        ParseTools.__init__(self)
        self.__dict__.update(args)
        self.html_rows = []

    def start_file_parser(self):
        tic = time.perf_counter()
        ### self.cache_files come in as part of the **args
        for file in self.cache_files:
            rows_on_page = self.get_rows_from_page_file(file)
            self.html_rows.extend(rows_on_page)

    def get_rows_from_page_file(self, file):
            strainer = SoupStrainer("tr")
            with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                strained_soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), features="html.parser", parse_only=strainer)
                return strained_soup

    def rebuild_row(self, row):
        new_row = []
        # loop selector disregards 'th' rows
        # the comparator uses .select() to disregard 'stars' and 'img'
        for col in row.select('td'):
            if col.select('div.stars, img'): 
                continue
            if col.a:
                links = self.handle_links(col)
                new_row.append(links)
            else:
                if not col.text or not col.text.strip():
                    new_row.append(['NaN'])
                else:
                    new_text = self.clean_tag_text(col)
                    new_row.append(new_text)
        return new_row

    def handle_links(self, col):
        links = col.find_all('a', href=True)
        if len(links) == 1:
            ### returns a tuple of (name, link)
            return [(self.clean_tag_text(links[0]), self.complete_url(links[0]['href']))]
        else:
            ### returns a tuple of (names, links)
            return [(self.clean_tag_text(tag), self.complete_url(tag['href'])) for tag in links]

    def complete_url(self, href_frag):
        return self.shelf_url + '/' + href_frag

    def clean_tag_text(self, tag):
        return tag.text.strip()
```

HTML row example:

```html
<tr id="groupBook3144889">
<td width="5%"><a href="/book/show/40851529-the-7th-of-victorica"><img alt="The 7th of Victorica by Beau Schemery" src="https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1531785241l/40851529._SY75_.jpg" title="The 7th of Victorica by Beau Schemery"/></a></td>
<td width="30%">
<a href="/book/show/40851529-the-7th-of-victorica">The 7th of Victorica (Gadgets and Shadows, #2)</a>
</td>
<td width="10%">
<a href="/author/show/6594115.Beau_Schemery">Schemery, Beau</a>
<span title="Goodreads Author!">*</span>
</td>
<td width="1%">
<div class="stars" data-rating="0" data-resource-id="40851529" data-restore-rating="null" data-submit-url="/review/rate/40851529?stars_click=false" data-user-id="0"><a class="star off" href="#" ref="" title="did not like it">1 of 5 stars</a><a class="star off" href="#" ref="" title="it was ok">2 of 5 stars</a><a class="star off" href="#" ref="" title="liked it">3 of 5 stars</a><a class="star off" href="#" ref="" title="really liked it">4 of 5 stars</a><a class="star off" href="#" ref="" title="it was amazing">5 of 5 stars</a></div>
</td>
<td width="1%">
<a class="actionLinkLite" href="/group/bookshelf/64285?shelf=read">read</a>, 
                    <a class="actionLinkLite" href="/group/bookshelf/64285?shelf=genre-action-adventure">genre-action-adve...</a>, 
                    <a class="actionLinkLite" href="/group/bookshelf/64285?shelf=genre-steampunk-dieselpunk">genre-steampunk-d...</a>, 
                    <a class="actionLinkLite" href="/group/bookshelf/64285?shelf=genre-young-adult">genre-young-adult</a>
</td>
<td width="1%">
                 
          </td>
<td width="1%">
                 
          </td>
<td width="1%">
<a href="/user/show/4872508-meghan"> Meghan</a>
</td>
<td width="1%">2022/12/25</td>
<td class="view" width="1%">
<a class="actionLink" href="/group/show_book/64285?group_book_id=3144889" style="white-space: nowrap">view activity »</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You've shown class methods but not the class. I will have to assume for the purposes of review that these are free-standing functions unless you add more code.

Comment: OK yeah you need to add code for your whole program. `handle_links` and `clean_tag_text` are missing, and since you always skip the first row of HTML your example will never produce any data

Comment: Moreover, you have a strainer for `table` but no table in your example

Comment: OK, thanks for feedback. I'm refactoring my code to break out the HTML file handling elsewhere. I'll just use `requests` for my update. Other info-- there's only one `table` on the page and after fumbling around I've adjusted my strainer to pick up `tr` instead of `table`. So thanks for that! I probably won't get a better code capture until tomorrow (maybe tonight). But I am still particularly stuck on `if col.div: if 'stars' in str(col.div.attrs): continue    if col.a: if col.a.img: continue`

Comment: I added an answer for my second question above. My biggest remaining question  is if there's a faster way to extract rows from a single HTML table in multiple local HTML files.

Comment: Actually, I filled in the code requested initially in the **UPDATE** section. I think that covers the import bits.